# Canvas DrawImage() poor quality

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a problem with Html5 canvas

i draw an image but its quality becomes very poor
[image]

after i draw it with canvas it becomes this

[image]

my code is here

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$canvasWidth = $('#canvas').width;
$canvasHeight = $('#canvas').height;
var alpha = 0.0;

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


function draw(){
    var delta = 0.05;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,$canvasWidth, $canvasHeight);
    ctx.globalAlpha = alpha;

    var logo= new Image();

    WandioLight.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(logo, 0, 0, 250, 167);

    };

    logo.src = "logo.png";

    alpha += delta;
    if(alpha > 1.0){
        return false;
    }
    setTimeout(draw, 50);
}
```

Comment: do you set the canvas width and height from css file ?

Comment: <canvas class="wandio-logo" width="250px" height="167px" id="canvas"></canvas>

i have this in html

Comment: I believe this is a scaling issue that occurs when setting `width` and `height` try doing it with the `style` attribute.

Comment: what is the logo file width and height ?

Comment: original with and height is 1000X669

Comment: please upload the code to jsfiddle and i will look at it

Comment: when you draw big image into small canvas with simple drawImage(), you always get bad quality, you need to use advanced resize/resample functions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image]

You can incrementally scale your image down for better results.

Since your final size is 1/4 the original size, you could:

- scale the 1000x669 image in half to 500x334 onto a temp canvas
- scale the 500x335 canvas in half to 250x167 onto the main canvas

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://ictcluster.ge/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/wandio-logo-1-1024x724.png";
function start(){


  // scale the 1000x669 image in half to 500x334 onto a temp canvas
  var c1=scaleIt(img,0.50);

  // scale the 500x335 canvas in half to 250x167 onto the main canvas
  canvas.width=c1.width/2;
  canvas.height=c1.height/2;
  ctx.drawImage(c1,0,0,250,167);

}

function scaleIt(source,scaleFactor){
  var c=document.createElement('canvas');
  var ctx=c.getContext('2d');
  var w=source.width*scaleFactor;
  var h=source.height*scaleFactor;
  c.width=w;
  c.height=h;
  ctx.drawImage(source,0,0,w,h);
  return(c);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```